# How to change the background color of the dropdown options on mouse over?

Tags: javascript, html, css, asp.net, vb.net

I have the following drop down list:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlSubdivision" AppendDataBoundItems="true"
runat="server" Height="30px" Width="450px" AutoPostBack="True"
OnSelectedIndexChanged="SubDivision_Changed" CssClass="dropdown"
OnClick ="">
```

In this dropdown list, I want to change the color of the options on mouse over. By default, in Chrome it shows up as Blue, but I want to change it to red.

I have tried the following CSS code:

```
   .dropdown {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

option::selection {
  background: #ffb7b7; /* WebKit/Blink Browsers */
}
```

But this does not seem to work. How to achieve the required functionality?

Comment: Styling dropdowns is very limited, it's usually best to use a plugin to create a html list so you can style that instead - [see this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7208786/how-to-style-the-option-of-an-html-select-element).  If you scroll down, there is [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7208786/how-to-style-the-option-of-an-html-select-element#answer-28466918) that shows some plugins you can use

Answer (score 0):

You can try with:

`!important`

> option:: selection { background: #ffb7b7 !important;}

Comment: No, this does not work :( Still the same blue color

Comment: If it does not work, I do not know. There is also ```!veryimportant``` which precedes ```!important```, but I do not think that will solve your problem.